# How to create a video thumbnail from a video file path in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdcard, video-thumbnails

I want to create a thumbnail of a video from the SD card path. How can I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `ThumbnailUtils` class to get Video thumbnail of Video file.

`createVideoThumbnail()` is method which return Bitmap (thumbnail) of video from video file path.

From Android Docs:

> **public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)**
>
> *Create a video thumbnail for a video. May return null if the video is
>   corrupt or the format is not supported.*

You can create VideoThumbnail from sdcard path like this.

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Using `ThumbnailUtils`, you can create thumbnail of two types.

1. `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND` type will generate thumbnail of size 96 x 96.
2. `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` type will generate thumbnail of size 512 x 384.

I hope it helps!

Comment: No it does not. it only works with video files that are in storage

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work for the videos that are on SD Card (External Storage) on Android 5.0+.  It returned null bitmap

Comment: @Riten how are you getting filepath and on which andorid os?

Comment: How can I set the filepath from a video on the raw folder?

Comment: If you're getting null bitmap then try to run it in real device and not in emulator. I wasted hours in emulator testing.

Comment: Chances of getting out of memory errors are high on this.

Comment: how about the .flv or .avi file?

Comment: doen't help in my case :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are directly creating thumbnails as follows

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

> Then there is a problem with this method if your are creating thumbnails for large video set(for large number of videos). the application will freeze until all the thumbnails are loaded because all the process are executing in the main thread.

**Use SuziLoader**

This loader will load the thumbnails for the videos which is locally stored on your filesystem in background.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video.mp4";
ImageView mThumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

SuziLoader loader = new SuziLoader(); //Create it for once
loader.with(MainActivity.this) //Context
    .load(path) //Video path
    .into(mThumbnail) // imageview to load the thumbnail
    .type("mini") // mini or micro
    .show(); // to show the thumbnail
```

> To get this dependency use the following steps

**Step 1.** Add the JitPack repository to your build file
Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.sushinpv:SuziVideoThumbnailLoader:0.1.0'
}
```

ADD READ EXTERNAL STORAGE Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check my code hope it will help you

```
/**
     * Retrieve video frame image from given video path
     * 
     * @param p_videoPath
     *            the video file path
     * 
     * @return Bitmap - the bitmap is video frame image
     * 
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String p_videoPath)
            throws Throwable
    {
        Bitmap m_bitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever m_mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
        try
        {
            m_mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            m_mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(p_videoPath);
            m_bitmap = m_mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
        }
        catch (Exception m_e)
        {
            throw new Throwable(
                    "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String p_videoPath)"
                            + m_e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (m_mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
            {
                m_mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            }
        }
        return m_bitmap;
    }
```

Modify above method according to your need