# How do I create video thumbnails in Codename one?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to generate thumbnail like images from a stored video in codename one?

I have a codename list that uses the generic renderer and has a list of strings which are a local path to either a video or an image. Is there a way to display either the image or a thumbnail of the video on the multiButton icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll need to use a native interface.  Looks like both iOS and Android support thumbnails from video.

[Getting a thumbnail from a video url or data in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)

[How to create video thumbnail from video file path in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517124/how-to-create-video-thumbnail-from-video-file-path-in-android)

You could also do it server-side and then load the thumbnails from your app.  E.g. Cloudinary supports generating video thumbnails.
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery

The Cloudinary cn1lib is available here:
https://github.com/shannah/cloudinary-codenameone