# how can I show a video thumbnail from a video path?

Tags: android, file, imageview, android-bitmap, video-thumbnails

I want to show a video thumbnail in an ImageView from a video path on storage. Is there a function that takes a video path and returns a bitmap of a thumbnail? I get the video path by this code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllMedia() {
  HashSet<String> videoItemHashSet = new HashSet<>();
  String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
  Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
  try {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
      videoItemHashSet.add((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ArrayList<String> downloadedList = new ArrayList<>(videoItemHashSet);
  return downloadedList;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create video thumbnail from video file path in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517124/how-to-create-video-thumbnail-from-video-file-path-in-android)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the default way to create a thumbnail.

**For Mini Kind**

```
Bitmap thumb;
//MINI_KIND, size:  512 x 384 thumbnail 
    thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            img_tumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

**For Micro Kind**

```
Bitmap thumb;
//MICRO_KIND, size: 96 x 96 thumbnail
thumb= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
img_tumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

Also, you can use Glide for Url as well as Video path of Device.

```
Glide.with(context).with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(videoFilePath) // or URI/path
                    .into(imgView); //imageview to set thumbnail to
```

also, you can resize thumbnail by using `.override(50,50)` with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: I tested your code but did not work. when I tried to use glide to load picture android studio got an error:                                
           Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: enable `multidexing` , this is the different problem and what error is showing?

Comment: this is the error:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex –

Comment: have you enabled `multidexing`  in Gradle , if you did not, then use `android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}` in app/build.gradle

Answer (score 6):

Use [Glide lib](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

to show thumbnail from local storage

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/example_video.mp4";

GlideApp  
    .with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)))
    .into(imageViewGifAsBitmap);
```

Comment: I tested your code but did not work. when I tried to use glide to load picture android studio got an error:                                
           Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: This error is related multidex. enable multidex for your project and try

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ThumbnailUtils` to load video thumb in 3 format:

- **MINI_KIND** : Good for media detail view
- **FULL_SCREEN_KIND** : Good for header
- **MICRO_KIND** : Good for recycleView

Ex:

```
holder.videoThumb.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(getItem(position).videoURL, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND))
```

The biggest drawback is that **ThumbnailUtils operate on UI thread** so if you try to use this method in a recycleView then it gone make your app skip frames. Your RecycleView will have laggy scroll and **if you have more than 7 items then your app will start throwing ANR**.

That means you need to create AsyncTask or Threads which again might lead to memory leaks.

### Conclusion; Glide is better in loading video thumbs.

Here `DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT` is important parameter which worked for me and give a smooth fast scroll in recycle view.

```
            Glide.with(context).load(getItem(position).videoURL)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .into(holder.videoThumb)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have 3rd method to set thumbnail of image/video.
Hope it will help you.

1) ThumbnailUtils --> Effective but Slow

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(thumbPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        holder.ivThumb.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

2)  [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) --> Very Effective but Slow

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(thumbPath);
       thumb.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(0));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Assume this is a corrupt  file
    }
```

3) [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) --> Effective and Fast

```
   RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(thumPath)
            .apply(options)
            .into(thumb);
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a Kotlin version. You can try this extension function.
It is using [coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/).

```
/**
 * https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/413
 */
fun ImageView.setThumbnail(uri: Uri, frameMillis: Long = 2000) {

    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .componentRegistry {
            add(VideoFrameFileFetcher(context))
            add(VideoFrameUriFetcher(context))
        }.build()

    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(uri)
        .videoFrameMillis(frameMillis)
        .target(this)
        .fetcher(VideoFrameUriFetcher(context))
        .build()

    findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()?.lifecycleScope?.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        imageLoader.execute(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some devices not working for me without **FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder**

So I used following code with FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder

```
 public static void loadLocalVideoThumbanail(Context context, String path, final ImageView imageView) {
    try {
        if (path == null || path.isEmpty())
            return;

        BitmapPool bitmapPool = Glide.get(context).getBitmapPool();
        int microSecond = 1000000;// 1st second as an example
        VideoBitmapDecoder videoBitmapDecoder = new VideoBitmapDecoder(microSecond);
        FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder = new FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder(videoBitmapDecoder, bitmapPool, DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);


        Glide.with(context).load(path).asBitmap().thumbnail(0.6f)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .dontAnimate()
                .videoDecoder(fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder)
                .override(200,200)
                .into(imageView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MyLog.e(TAG, "LoadImage: ", e);
    }
}
```