# Generate a thumbnail from a video uri in android and convert it to base64

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a frame from the video (thumbnail) and convert it to base64. I have used the following code but sometimes it doesn't work:

```
        Uri selectedVideo = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("trimmedVideo"));

        MediaMetadataRetriever mMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mMMR.setDataSource(this, selectedVideo);
        Bitmap thumbnail = mMMR.getFrameAtTime();
        Log.d(Global.getTag(), "thumbnail: "+thumbnail);
```

Also I get this error in logcast:

```
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
```

And thumbnail is null. Thanks in advance.

Note:
I also try to use the next code but it doesn't work.

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32517167/13533028

**1st Method**

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

The Thumbnails part decides the type of thumbnail it will be.(big or small)

**2nd Method**

https://github.com/sushinpv/SuziVideoThumbnailLoader

This is a library which will make it easier for you to implement

**3rd Method**

Using Glide Library

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 Glide.with(getContext())
      .load("video_url")
      .apply(requestOptions)
      .thumbnail(Glide.with(getContext()).load("video_url"))
      .into("yourimageview");
```

Comment: I try with that but it returns null (1) and I need to have the thumbnail to convert it to base64, so I can't use 2.

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yes, and requested for API >= 23, but for now I'm using a cellphone with API 22 so that doesn't matter. Also the crash happens sometimes not all the time, I read that MediaMetadataRetriever sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: Added another implementation using glide library

Comment: I can't use Glide because I need the thumbnail to load it to ImageView BUT also I need to convert that thumbnail it to base64,