# Want to add thumbnail to videoview. in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Actually  in this
1.I want to add Thumbnail to my videoview.
2. In this I have 3 videoviews and even I want to make videoview to full screen.
I tried seeing many youtube videos still that didn't helped me. I tried doing that still I didn't got the expected output. Can anyone please help me.

this is my bvideos.java code.

```
public class bvideos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private MediaController mediaController;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bvideos);

        Button photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bphoto);
        photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent y = new Intent(bvideos.this, mainpage.class);
                startActivity(y);

            }
        });


        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bvideo1);
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        /*videoView.start();*/

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view2);
        Uri videoUri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bvideo2);

        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri1);

        mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        /*videoView.start();*/

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view3);

        Uri videoUri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bvideo3);

        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri2);

        mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32517167/13533028

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5950165/13533028

**1st Method**

```
Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

The Thumbnails part decides the type of thumbnail it will be.(big or small)

**2nd Method**

https://github.com/sushinpv/SuziVideoThumbnailLoader

This is a library which will make it easier for you to implement

**3rd Method**
Using Glide

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_video_place_holder)
                .into(imageView);
```